# Como instalar pacotes no pip sem acesso à internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Estou com dificuldades no python.

Estou prestando serviço para uma empresa bancária, porém a rede é muito fechada, não consigo fazer o download dos arquivos via `pip`. Conseguo fazer os download dos pacotes de uma outra maneira mas não consigo fazer que eles executem, alguém pode me ajudar?

Detalhe: só funciona o `powershell`

Comment: Tente utilizar o WinPython, acredito que a instalação de pacotes pode ser realizada em um enviroment e transferido para outro por ser algo portable. Espero que te ajude.

Comment: então a maquina que eu utilizo não consigo fazer o download de absolutamente nada, eu meio que consegui fazendo uma gambiarra na rede, mas acho que nao vou conseguir utilizar o winpython,

Comment: Você pode transferir os pacotes manualmente, descompactá-los e rodar o programa 'setup.py' individualmente (acho que é "setup.py install"); o chato da abordagem é que você precisa manualmente resolver as dependências (tipo o módulo A precisa do módulo B, logo, instale primeiro o B).

Comment: Voce não consegue instalar diretamente os arquivos .whl(Whell)?

Comment: Tentou usar o [pip3 download -r requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) e levar um pendrive com estes? E realizar uma instalação offline.

Comment: entao, nao consigo abrir em arquivos .whl, e tbm nao consigo levar um pendrive pois o windows reconhece que nao é um  periférico e bloqueia, e o pip3 nao reconhece o termo kkkk( to rindo mas to chorando por dentro)

Answer (score 2):

Para instalar um arquivo `.whl` localmente, use `pip install` normalmente:

```
pip install arquivo.whl
pip install C:\Pasta\arquivo.whl
```

Se tiver dependências, você pode indicar uma pasta onde procurar as dependências:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links c:\Pasta programa
```

Se for em formato `.tar.gz` ou `.zip`, descompacte e procure o `setup.py` - se tiver, rode o `easy_install`:

```
easy_install --always-unzip --allow-hosts=None --find-links=c:\pasta
```

Ele vai procurar as dependências em `C:\Pasta`, coloque todos os arquivos que ele pedir lá.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, esse procedimento, obrigado